# local variable 'comment_form' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a BlogApp and I built a feature that if user disable comments ( through Boolean Field ) then the comments will be disabled. BUT i am stuck on an Error. When i open browser then it is showing me :-

> local variable 'comment_form' referenced before assignment

views.py

```
    def detail_view(request,id):
        data = get_object_or_404(Post,id=id)
        comments = data.comments.order_by('-created_at')
        new_comment = None

        if Post.allow_comments == True:
            if request.method == 'POST':
                comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
                if comment_form.is_valid():

            else:
                comment_form = CommentForm()

        else:
            print("Comments are Disabled")

        context = {'data':data,'comments':comments,'new_comment':new_comment,'comment_form':comment_form}
        return render(request, detail.html', context )
```

I don't know . What am i missing in this.

Comment: When `Post.allow_comments` is `False`, `comment_form` never gets defined.

Comment: request.POST is in your if statement, put it outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Comment form` is inside your `if statement`, if post.allow is `false`your form is not callable.

Change for the following :

```
def detail_view(request,id):
    data = get_object_or_404(Post,id=id)
    comments = data.comments.order_by('-created_at')
    new_comment = None
    comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)

    if Post.allow_comments == True:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if comment_form.is_valid():

                comment_form.instance.post_by = data
                comment_form.instance.commented_by = request.user
                comment_form.instance.active = True
                new_comment = comment_form.save()
                return redirect('mains:detail_view',id=id)

        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()

    else:
        print("Comments are Disabled")

    context = {'data':data,'comments':comments,'new_comment':new_comment,'comment_form':comment_form}
    return render(request, detail.html', context )
```